# Testing a conditionally rendered section of a React Functional Component (Jest + @testing-library/react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, snapshot-testing

This is about testing a component which has a state update within a `useEffect()`. The issue is that the component is always tested against its default state.

There is a bunch of problems that goes similar to this but I haven't found any successful way of testing the following.

**MyComponent.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoaded(true)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {loaded ? (
        <div data-testid="true-text"> -> line 13
          true
        </div> -> line 15
      ) : (
        <div data-testid="false-text">
          false
        </div>
      )}

    </div>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

**MyComponent.test.tsx**

```
/** @jest-environment jsdom */

import React from "react";
import MyComponent from "../awesome-component";
import { render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  test('should match snapshot', async () => {
    const setState = jest.fn()
    jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockImplementation(() => [false, setState]);

    const { asFragment, queryByTestId } = render(<MyComponent />);

    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(setState).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, true)
      expect(queryByTestId('false-text')).toBeTruthy()
    });
  });
});
```

**Test result**

```
 › 1 snapshot updated.
-----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                   | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files              |   88.46 |    66.66 |     100 |   88.46 |                   
 awesome-component.tsx |   88.46 |    66.66 |     100 |   88.46 | 13-15             
-----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Snapshot Summary
 › 1 snapshot updated from 1 test suite.
```

I need to test the component rendered when `loaded === true`.

From the statement `expect(setState).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, true)` I can see that the state update has happened but still `expect(queryByTestId('false-text')).toBeTruthy()` statement appears to be expecting correctly which means the template is rendered according to the `false` condition.

And in the coverage we can see that the `loaded === true` never rendered.

Can someone help me to evolve the same test to test after `setLoaded(true)`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't mock things you don't own. Replacing useState completely breaks your component, the value is always and explicitly false.

Comment: Hey thanks, i get it. Actually, removing the mocked `useState` allowed the component to be perfectly executed. But is there any way to test the `false` state now? Also how to check if correct values got updated in the state?

Comment: Or does it mean that only the end states can be tested? Hence, `loaded === false` can never be tested.

Comment: Presumably you don't _actually_ just immediately and unconditionally toggle the loading state (otherwise you might as well remove the `useEffect` and start with `true`). Probably something like `expect(screen.getByText("false")).toBeInTheDocument()` followed by `await expect(screen.findByText("true")).resolves.toBeInTheDocument()` would work, but without a [mre] of the real behaviour it's hard to say how you should test that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to mock the state of a react component. As per @jonsharpe's answer and my findings with the same idea, we should not try to change the behaviour of something that we do not own. This is different from mocking our own functions as we do know the behaviour or what we have written.

Instead, what we should do is trying to test the end states of components.